# JSLink Error 404

Tags: jslink

After deploying a JSLink file to add a button to a list view, I'm getting the following error when expecting the page in Chrome developer tools.
[image]

using the following to reference the item

```
~sitecollection/Site Assets/JSLinkAddCommentToManagerButton.js
```

here is the code:

```
(function () {
document.write('<style type="text/css">.btn {  background: #0072C6; 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0072C6, #2980b9);   
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0072C6, #2980b9);  background-
image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0072C6, #2980b9);  background-image: -o-
linear-gradient(top, #0072C6, #2980b9);  background-image: linear-  
gradient(to bottom, #0072C6, #2980b9);  font-family: Arial;  color: #ffffff;  font-size: 12px;  background: #0072C6;  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;  text-decoration: none; margin-right:10px;}<\/style>');
var statusFieldCtx = {};

statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
"Action": {
    "View": ShowButton
    }};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();


function ShowButton(ctx) {

var _ItemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
var TitleFeedback  = "Send Comment to Manager";

var TaskView = "/teams/MTS/Engagement/Lists/ShoutWall/DispForm.aspx?ID="+_ItemId;

return "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"openViewDialog('" + TaskView    + "', '" + TitleFeedback  + "')\" class='btn'>Add Comment</a>";
}

function openViewDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
       var options = {
         url: tUrl,
         title: tTitle,
         height:600,
         width:800,
         dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) 
         { 
              SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult) 
         }

 };
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }
```

Comment: Have you uploaded this JS file to Site Assets library in your site collection and Are you able to access this JS file using the link shown in chrome console?

Comment: moving the file to the Style Library solved the issue

Comment: For easy CSR development see the Cisar Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your URL is incorrect. There is no space in `SiteAssets`. The correct URL might be:

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JSLinkAddCommentToManagerButton.js
```

Plus, I personally prefer using `~site` rather than `~sitecollection` as it makes clear that anything being referred is inside the current web.

In any event while getting the URL you should always read it from the document's ECB menu, to avoid any mistakes.